# Core Plot - Disable axis labels for certain ticks

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, graph, core-plot

How would I disable the axis labels for certain (not all) ticks?

For example, my x-axis corresponds to the start time of an event.  The x-axis label shows the date of the start time.  However, there may be multiple events in one day, and instead of multiple labels displaying the same date, I'd like for only the first occurrence of the date to be shown, and remaining labels with the same date hidden.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked around and found this can be done with `labelExclusionRanges`.

From Core Plot documentation:

> CPTAxis: [read, write, retain]
>
> An array of CPTPlotRange objects. Any tick marks and labels falling inside any of the ranges in the array will not be drawn.